# Mod_rewrite rule - [L] not working as expected

Tags: url-rewrite, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a `mod_rewrite` rule that will handle transparently rewriting a friendly URL to a query string redirect behind the browser.

Every  tutorial says to use the `last` flag [L]

but this does not work, per se. or it seems not to.

The original URL that works looks like this

```
http://<domain>/locations?state=123&city=343
```

my friendly URL looks like this

```
http://<domain>/locations/123/343
```

my rewrite rule looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /locations/
RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)/(.*)$ /locations?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

I get a 404 error when I try to his my friendly URL

however, if I add the `redirect` flag [R]

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /locations/
RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)/(.*)$ /locations?state=$1&city=$2 [R, L]
```

The URL redirects  and  the page loads, however the address bar gets updated to read

```
http://<domain>/locations?state=123&city=343
```

Why does the redirect work but the non-redirect not?
is it because it's too late for Apache to consume the rewritten URL and re-parse it to the actual final URL?

How might I get around this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an HTACCESS question

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. This does not look like a Magento related question, because Magento works with "friendly" URLs instead of `?state=x&city=y` out of the box, so there are no additional mod_rewrite rules required. If it actually is about Magento, please try to explain what you are trying to achieve to get an answer how to solve it in code. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: (otherwise try your luck at serverfault.com instead)